# Show only the element in a particular Div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-hover

Just stuck with an issue here. I have multiple divs, which on hover shows a `Span` that contains some text. I have created the a jquery script, but the same shows all the `Span` when i hover the mouse on another `Div`.

In short. I need to show the `SPAN` on the `DIV` where I hover the mouse, rest of the `SPAN` should be hidden.

Here is code

```
$('.proimg').hover(function () {
    $('.proimg span').show();
}, function () {
    $('.proimg span').hide();
});
```

Any help id much appreciated and thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you show a little more code: at least the HTML of two divs and their spans - the minimum needed to reproduce what you are seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.proimg').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('span').show();
},function () {
    $(this).find('span').hide();
});
```

Comment: You hit the Bulls Eye .. Sir... Many Thanks.. A small question does it target only the SPAN under the parent .proimg Div

Comment: This will find all span children of the .proimg element being hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the child spans of the specific div that are hovering over using the `$(this)` selector:

```
$('.proimg').hover (function(){
    $(this).children('span').show ();
    },
    function () {
    $(this).children('span').hide();
});
```